# Read file in which its name changes daily python

Tags: python, csv, readfile

I need to read a .csv which name is changing over time.
For intance, yesterday it was '58724_route_48878.csv' and today its name is '32840_route_41124.csv'.

It always keeps in the name '*route*' but numbers before and after that word changes every day.
Is there a way to read the file without changing the file name detailed in the script daily?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `glob.glob('*_route_*.csv')` to get all the files that match that pattern.

Comment: The problem is that not all files are called in the same way so I have no pattern (one file is '328914_route_4089.csv', another file is '7438_plot_329i42.csv'. They keep for instance route and plot in their names but numbers change)

Comment: The question says "It always keeps in the name 'route'"

Comment: Use `*_plot_*.csv` for the `plot` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any way to predict how the numbers change in the file name, then your best bet is to use `glob`, a Python library that lets you list files in a directory that match a certain wildcard pattern. `glob` is documented at [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)

```
import glob
file_path = glob.glob('*_route_*.csv')[0] # use [0] to pick the first matching file
```

Note that the sample code above picks the first matching file in the current directory. If there are going to be multiple files that match that pattern, you'll have to come up with more logic to pick the correct one.